# Do "worn out" and "worn" convey the same meaning?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences

I've seen the following sentences in a book.

The brake shoes are worn out.

The tires are worn.

I'm wondering when to use "worn" and when to use "worn out".

***Longman Dictionary:***

**Worn**: a worn object is old and damaged, especially because it has been used a lot

**Worn out**: too old or damaged to be used

It seems that "worn out" and "worn" have the same meaning. Do I need to be careful when using "worn out" and "worn"?

Comment: They are different, as your example definitions show, crucially in the "_to be used_" of _Worn out_.  _Worn_ can be applied almost as soon as something is not in "brand new" condition, but usually while it is still usable. _Worn out_ implies that it cannot (or at least should not) be used (safely) anymore.

Comment: 'Worn out' is, if you like, one endpoint on the spectrum of 'worn'.

Comment: No two words can be used interchangeably. Not in English, not in any language. That's why they are two words and not one word.

Comment: @RegDwigнt . I edited the title of the question. I agree with you, but sometimes it is not easy to realize the differences. For example, I am still waiting for a better answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405325/do-real-life-applications-and-real-world-applications-convey-the-same-meanin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **worn out** object is an object that has been **worn** to the point of uselessness.

For instance, the brake shoe would be **worn** if the lining was visibly abraded, it would be **worn out** if it was abraded to the point where the lining was worn away altogether, resulting in metal on metal contact.

Comment: *Worn out* is rendered in some UK dialects as *worn up*.

Comment: @WS2 Any clues as to which dialects? Not doubting it is used, given the range and weirdness of dialects, just that I've never (consciously) heard _worn up_ used. Also, there's _worn down_ which doesn't necessarily imply completely _worn out_, but tends to cover the _very worn_ end of the spectrum that Spagirl mentions in a comment.